# How to prevent toolbar from collapsing after scroll?

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

[image]

After scroll, I don't want the toolbar to collapse but only the ImageView, similar to exitUntillCollapsed. But I want the app bar to expand on slightest downward scroll. How do I achieve this?

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
       android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewCollapsing"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/winterscenery"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
       </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For scroll behaviour pls use flag `enterAlways`

For Fix toolbar layout pls add toolbarlayout above your coordinatorLayout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewCollapsing"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/winterscenery"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />


            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: But in your answer the toolbar is also getting retracted on upward scroll. I don't want the toolbar to collapse in any condition. Only the image view should expand or collapse on scroll.

Comment: pls provide your full layout.xml

Comment: pls check the images in the question description